# Extended Validation certificate, how do display the extended credentials on mobile devices?

Tags: ssl-certificate

With the rise of mobile phone and tablet browsing I've noticed that there's no display of Extended Validation certificates. Just the same green padlock as a plain ol' $5 certificate.

In a desktop browser, you have a lovely green bar, and a green box with the company name on it. This adds trust and confidence in the domain, the company and the website.

How can I indicate to users that I have the extended validation certificate?

Comment: Feel free to ask the "how do you enhance their trust as an EV would?" question on UX, but it's too subjective a question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia, [Extended Validation certificate is supported in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate#Supported_Mobile_Device_Browsers):

- Safari for iOS
- Windows Phone
- Blackberry

On my iPhone it is displayed in a way similar to desktop browsers:

[image: Extended Validation certificate on Safari for iOS]

The only platform I couldn't find any information about current or planned support of EV certificates is Android. [Answers to this question on security.stachexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52387/does-google-use-extended-validation-certificates) suggest that Google isn't fond of implementing different display for EV certificates.